# Change date string from Dutch to English to use it in strtotime

Tags: php, date, datetime, localization

I have the following Dutch string date:

```
dinsdag, 18 april 2017
```

Now I want to strip the day and the month, and I can do that with the following example, but that doesn't work because its in Dutch and strtotime only works with English strings.

```
$stripDay = date('d',strtotime($date));
$stripMonth = date('m',strtotime($date));
```

So I checked for other options, and I found strptime function which states that it can work.

```
$format = '%l, %d %m %Y';
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');    
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
```

First I configured the format, and then I set the Locale. But if I use the following code it still gives me 1's back.

```
$stripDay = date('d',strptime($date));
$stripMonth = date('m',strptime($date));
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define array which contain english days and dutch day and then you can replace dutch string with english string like this:

```
<?php
    function dutch_strtotime($datetime) {
        $days = array(
            "maandag"   => "Monday",
            "dinsdag"   => "Tuesday",
            "woensdag"  => "Wednesday",
            "donderdag" => "Thursday",
            "vrijdag"   => "Friday",
            "zaterdag"  => "Saturday",
            "zondag"    => "Sunday"
        );

        $months = array(
            "januari"   => "January",
            "februari"  => "February",
            "maart"     => "March",
            "april"     => "April",
            "mei"       => "May",
            "juni"      => "June",
            "juli"      => "July",
            "augustus"  => "August",
            "september" => "September",
            "oktober"   => "October",
            "november"  => "November",
            "december"  => "December"
        );

        $array = explode(" ", $datetime);
        $array[0] = $days[strtolower($array[0])];
        $array[2] = $months[strtolower($array[2])];
        return strtotime(implode(" ", $array));
    }
    $date = "woensdag 22 oktober 2014 08:41:42";
    echo date("l d-m-Y H:i:s", dutch_strtotime($date)) . "<br />";
    echo date("d-m-Y", dutch_strtotime($date));
?>
```

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I marked it as the solution. Still a shame I have to do it like this and not just make it a datetime but I guess sometimes it just doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @HuubS - if you've got `Intl` running you can use PHP's `IntlDateFormatter` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running PHP with `Intl` you can use the [IntlDateFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php) class rather than rolling your own translations:

```
$df = IntlDateFormatter::create(
    'nl_NL', 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    'Europe/Amsterdam',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'eeee, d MMMM yyyy'
    );

// since the time is omitted from the string
// it uses 00:00 - which meant the timestamp
// was an hour off for me in the UK so it
// was rolling the date back to 23:00 the
// previous day. Forcing UTC sorts this.
$df->setTimeZone('Etc/UTC');

// outputs '2017-04-18'
echo date('Y-m-d', $df->parse('dinsdag, 18 april 2017'));
```

You'll probably need the [ICU date format guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) handy though as it's different to *normal* PHP date formatting (hence 'eeee' for the day).